# Проблема с list index out of range при выполнении замены в .txt файле

Tags: python

```
name_old = input("Write your old login: ")
password_old = input("Write your old password: ")
file = open("F:\programme\logins.txt", "r")

array = []
for line in file:
    array.append(line.split(" "))

for i in array:
    end_login = i[0].find(";") - 1
    end_pas = i[1].find(";") - 1
    login = i[0][5:end_login]
    pasw = i[1][5:end_pas]
    if name_old == login and password_old == pasw:
        name_new = input("Write new login: ")
        password_new = input("Write new password: ")
        old_data = file.read()
        new_data = old_data.replace(name_old and password_old, name_new and password_new)
file.close()
with open ('F:\programme\logins.txt', 'w') as f:
    f.write(new_data)
```

В текстовом файле хранится

> log:"admin"; pas:"admin";
>
> log:"joly"; pas:"joly";

ошибка находится в строке `end_pas = i[1].find(";") - 1`

Помогите пожалуйста исправить эту ошибку.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Советую при отладке печатать в консоль значения `end_login`, `end_pas`, `login`, `pasw`.

Так как `i[1]` в конце имеет символ конца строки `\n`, то нужно вычитать `2`.
Поэтому у Вас `if` ни разу не выполняется, и скорее всего программа падает на завершающей файл `logins.txt` пустой строке, которая не имеет пробела, поэтому не разбивается на два элемента.

Данный блок совсем нехорош:

```
    old_data = file.read()
    new_data = old_data.replace(name_old and password_old, name_new and password_new)
```

1. Файл уже считан, чтобы считать его снова, его нужно перемотать вначало `file.seek(0)`
2. `old_data.replace(name_old and password_old, name_new and password_new)` - очень по-человечески понятно, но неправильно. Правильно: `old_data.replace(name_old, name_new).replace(password_old, password_new)`
3. Такой подход совершенно нехорош тем, что заменяет все вхождения name_old и password_old в файле, а не конкретную найденную запись. Более правильный подход - пересоздать запись i, которая уже найдена. Не забыть сделать `break` для выхода из цикла.

```
   i[0] = 'log:"{0}";'.format(name_new)
   i[1] = 'pas:"{0}\n";'.format(password_new)
   break
```

А потом в отдельном цикле пересоздать весь файл паролей:

```
    with open ('F:\programme\logins.txt', 'w') as f:
        for i in array:
             f.write(" ".join(i))
```